# Without creating a list, how can I query the integers between two values in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

For example, if I make a query like `between(1,4,X)?` I would expect something like `X=2`, `X=3`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 between(A,B,X):-X is A+1,X<B.
 between(A,B,X):-A2 is A+1,A2<B-1,between(A2,B,X).
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still at my beginning states of learning Prolog and I was stuck with this.

Comment: It took me ages to figure out that you need to use the 'is' keyword to do "assignment".

Comment: "is" actually is not "assignment". Instead, it performs a numerical computation on the RHS, and then a unification with the LHS.

Comment: `between/3` is a commonly predefined predicate that includes the borders. A different name for this other predicate would help confusion in many systems. Also, `between(1,1000000000000,0).` takes a lot of time to fail.